# Is there an improper subset that isn't equal to its superset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Can there be a set $A$ and a set $B$ such that $A\subseteq B$ and $A\ne B$ ?

While trying to find a solution to this question, I've found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2370900/612647) which states:

> An improper subset (usually denoted as $A\subseteq B$) is such that $A=B$ **is allowed (but not mandated)**

If that's true, can you give an example for such a case where $A\ne B$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, $A= \{1\}$, $B =\{1,2\}$, will do. Or $A = \emptyset$ and $B$ *any* non-empty set, like $\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: Aren't those examples of proper sets, since $A$ does not contain $2$?

Comment: @Noam there is no such thing as a proper set here. Both are sets and $A$ is a proper subset of $B$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a proper subset, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) defines a subset as proper if "there exists at least one element of B which is not an element of A"

Comment: @Noam $A\subseteq B$ means only that all elements of $A$ are in $B$ as well.

Comment: Oh, it finally clicked! $\subseteq$ and $\subset$ aren't opposites!

Comment: @Noam Indeed. $\subset$ is used by some authors as a *synonym* for $\subseteq$, by others as an alternative for $A\subsetneq B$, which can both mean "all elements of $A$ are in $B$, but *not* $A = B$". The negation of $A \subseteq B$ is "there is some $a \in A$ that is *not* in $B$", denoted by $A \not\subseteq B$, e.g.

Answer (score 0):

If you can prove for every $x$ in A is also in B but inverse is not true, you will finish.
This is your proving motivation. For example: let $A={(1,2,3)}$ and $B={(1,2,3,4)}$ two sets.
We have for all $x$ in $A$, $x$ is also in B. But there exist a $y$ in $B$ (which is $4$)
which is not in $A$.
So we have finally:

$A⊆B$ and  $A≠B$