# What is the difference between an improper subset and equal sets?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I've searched a lot but couldn't help myself with the distinction between an improper subset and equal sets. I would appreciate if someone could help me here.

Comment: No difference...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is an improper subset?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370884/what-exactly-is-an-improper-subset)

Comment: No. If there's no difference, then why are there two different names for a same thing?

Comment: In fact, "improper subset" is a useless description; what we have is the *subset* relation: $A \subseteq B \leftrightarrow \forall x (x \in A \to x \in B)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think this is worth an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The starting point is the rigorous definition of the [*subset* relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#Definition):

> $A \subseteq B \leftrightarrow \forall x (x \in A \to x \in B)$.

According to this definition, we have that every set is subset of itself and that the empty set is subset of every set. That's all.

But we can exploit the analogy with the $\le$ relation and we may say that $A$ is a *proper* subset of $B$ just in case that $A \subseteq B$ and $A \ne B$ [in symbol: $\subsetneq$].

If we want, we can use the - IMO useless - notion of "improper" subset, i.e. of a subset that is not a proper subset, that means that the only "improper subset" of $A$ is $A$ itself.

And finally, it is worth noting that in set theory [equlity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215177/should-this-definition-of-set-equality-be-an-axiom) can be defined as mutual inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

A **proper subset** of a set *S* is any subset of *S* besides *S* itself and the empty set. So an improper subset would be either $S$ or $\emptyset$. Equality, of course, would be $S$.

Comment: Why besides the empty set?

Comment: @Damian, that’s how I’ve most often seen *improper subset* used. This notion excludes the two (dual) extreme cases—all or nothing—leaving behind only the interesting ones.

Comment: I've always seen "proper subset" only to mean not equal to full set, i.e. just like a strict inequality. I'm sure I've seen "non-empty proper subset" used several times.

Comment: I've only seen proper subset refer to strict subsets, so the empty set is a proper subset unless the set is also itself empty.